# Mendeley's standard IEEE CSL file creates improper bibliography

Tags: ieee, mendeley, csl

I have been using Mendeley's Microsoft Word plugin to easily reference papers in my Mendeley Desktop library.

However, I've noticed that the IEEE format for the bibliography/citation is incorrect with regards to referencing conference proceedings and theses.

On the IEEE citation guide: http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf

It shows that the city of the conference should be included in the citation of a conference paper. However, Mendeley's IEEE CSL file does not include this detail.

```
 <macro name="event">
<choose>
  <if type="paper-conference speech" match="any">
    <choose>
      <!-- Published Conference Paper -->
      <if variable="container-title">
        <group delimiter=", ">
          <group delimiter=" ">
            <text term="in"/>
            <text variable="container-title" font-style="italic"/>
          </group>
          <text variable="event-place"/>
        </group>
```

Should be changed to:

```
 <macro name="event">
<choose>
  <if type="paper-conference speech" match="any">
    <choose>
      <!-- Published Conference Paper -->
      <if variable="container-title">
        <group delimiter=", ">
          <group delimiter=" ">
            <text term="in"/>
            <text variable="container-title" font-style="italic"/>
          </group>
          <text variable="publisher-place"/>
        </group>
```

Since event-place is not a keyword that maps to the "city" field in Mendeley; the correct variable is "publisher-place".

Answer (score 6):

Two options, use this formatted one that I just made, or follow the steps I did to make this change in the CSL Visual Editor.

**Just use the corrected file**

1. While in Mendeley Desktop, go to View menu, "Citation Style ->" and click "More Styles..."
2. Click on the tab "Get More Styles", and enter the following link into the "Download Style:" text box, then click Download

http://csl.mendeley.com/styles/451326401/ieee-CS-edited

Done!

**Make your own corrections**

1. While in Mendeley Desktop, go to View menu, "Citation Style ->" and click "More Styles..."
2. Right Click on IEEE and choose "Copy Style Link"
3. Open up a web browser, and paste the link and hit enter, it should download a file called "ieee.csl"
4. Open up a web browser that isn't Chrome, as this doesn't work in Chrome, and go to the page http://csl.mendeley.com/visualEditor/
5. Login using your Mendeley credentials
6. Click on the "Visual editor" tab at the top if it's not already selected.
7. Hover over "Style" and choose "Load Style..."
8. Browse and select the "ieee.csl" file that was downloaded earlier.
9. Under "STYLE INFO" and "Info", rename the Title to something new.
10. Navigate to the following

`BIBLIOGRAPHY`

`->Layout`

`-->Conditional`

`--->Else-of paper-conference OR...`

`---->Group`

`----->event (macro)`

`------>Conditional`

`------->If paper-conference OR speech`

`-------->Conditional`

`--------->If container-title`

`--------->Group`

`----------->event-place (variable)`

11. Click on event-place (variable) and in the editable section to the right, change the variable from "event-place" to "publisher-place"
12. Then go back to the Style menu and choose "Save Style As..."
13. Save this style, and it should automatically add it to your Mendeley Desktop

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Mendeley does not show the thesis citations correctly in IEEE format. It should be like this:

[1] J. K. Author, “Title of thesis,” M.S. thesis, Abbrev. Dept., Abbrev. Univ., City of Univ., Abbrev. State, year.
[2] J. K. Author, “Title of dissertation,” Ph.D. dissertation, Abbrev. Dept., Abbrev. Univ., City of Univ., Abbrev. State,
year.

However, the thesis type and department name are not showing!!